# Canvas to Image

Tags: html, canvas

I need to convert the canvas tag into a image file and it need to support the IE6+,Mozilla 3+
and saffari 5+

Comment: How is it possible ...this is the question.

Comment: It treat IE as a Bitch.. sorry for slang

Answer (score 4):

There ain't no way IE6 supports canvas.  It's not even supported in IE8...

Answer (score 1):

Take a screenshot?

Answer (score 1):

ExplorerCanvas doesn't allow saving as an image using Javascript, since it's VML and not Canvas. You can get the XML source of a VML image, but you'd still need a back-end script to parse the VML and save it to an image file.

You could also use the [fxCanvas](http://code.google.com/p/fxcanvas) library to fake canvas in IE. This library does support toDataURL(), but requires the Flash plugin.

Other browsers and Internet Explorer 9 support canvasElement.[toDataURL()](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl) natively.

Answer (score 0):

In Firefox the browser displays the canvas element as an image on the client side, so your user can right click the canvas and use the "save-image" functionality to get the image.

Safari doesn't support this, but it is possible to save the 
image using javascript as described in [this blog post](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/)

to use the canvas element in ie < 9 (at least parts of it) you could use the 
[explorercanvas](http://code.google.com/p/explorercanvas/) javascript library, but i don't know if it supports saving the content 
as an element.

another possibility is using svg to render images on the serverside or in an applet using 
the [batik-framework](http://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) from apache

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Flash, it's not possible in native HTML5 in IE6-IE8:  http://flashcanvas.net/

You will want to look into Downloadify and JSZip if you want to allow users to download those images to their desktop (it allows the users to give custom names to the files, and choose where they're saved).